# PHP topic viewing and replying script

Tags: php

I'm working on a small board/forum.  I have topic posting done; it's visible in the database and all that jazz.  Now I'm working on retrieving the topic list and so that when you click a topic you can view it. That's working fine, except that when I click on it the page goes blank and nothing is being shown.  I know the issue is that I can't get the id of the post I clicked on because it's in the if-else statement with a while loop.  Here is my code now.

```
<?php
  require('init.php');

  $get_threads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GOT ORDER BY time");
  if (!isset($_GET['view_thread'])) {
    $get_threads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GOT ORDER BY time");
    while ($select_threads = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_threads)) {
      $title = $select_threads['title'];
      $time = $select_threads['time'];
      $user = $select_threads['user'];
      $id = $select_threads['id'];
      $form = '<center>
               <form method="get" action="">
               <input type="submit" name="view_thread" id="view_thread" value="'.$title.'" />
               <input type="hidden" name="thread_id" id="thread_id" value="'.$id.'" />
               </form>
               </center>';
      echo '<div id="post_info">'.$form.'<hr>Posted by: <b>'.$user.'</b> '.$time.'</div>';
    }
  } else {
    $get_posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GOT WHERE id='$id'");
    $select_posts = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_posts);
    $content = $select_posts['content'];
    echo $content;
  }
?>
```

I need to get that `$id` so I can grab the post and later all the replies from the database. I'm new to php so I'm probably missing something. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please add  $id=$_GET['thread_id']; after  } else {

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score -1):

first: your parameter is named "thread_id", so your query should be

```
$get_posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GOT WHERE id='$thread_id'");
```

BUT i strongly suggest to

1. go for POST instead of GET
2. use mysql_real_escape to avoid SQL injection

Comment: If I use post people wouldnt be able to navigate to topics by using the URL.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @NardCake: I suggest to use POST in FORMS, not in normal links 
orourkek: the question was about this script, and the OP states he's quite a newbie in PHP programming; i think that the first thing to do was make his script work, which I did; second suggest a simpler way to strenghten the security,  I didn't feel like saing: "trash all your code in a couple of years the won't work animore"